# No target field in Opportunity to match source Lead field - Lead Field Mapping

Tags: lead-conversion

How do I send field email from lead when I convert from opportunity I made a look up field in opportunity to Lead and I made a custom field in lead, but when I go to "Lead Custom Field Mapping" there is no drop box to check from its empty. it says send email over None Available .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field mappings have to be a compatible data type. A look up field can only map to another look up field. Make a new field on Opportunity that is a compatible data type (e.g. text, email).

Comment: there is an email field in lead that goes to  under contact, is it possible to map that out? right now I am making extra field in lead called email send over and that is the one for mapping. but I want the native email field to be accessible . I want to call it in my work flow under oppurtunity that is why I need it